# Conference in Los Angeles, visa?

Tags: visas, esta, los-angeles, italian-citizens

I'm going to LA next month to attend a conference. I went to South Korea in the past (for few days) and I didn't need to do anything. Except signing a couple of things at the airport before leaving (explaining why I'm staying how many days etc).

In LA I'm going to stay for about a week, and I've never been there.
What do I need to do documentation wise, how do I get a visa?

PS: I'm flying from the UK and I'm an Italian citizen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an Italian citizen you don't need a visa to attend a conference in the US. All you need is an ESTA, which you apply for online: https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/. Only if that is denied do you need to get a proper visa. All you need for travelling once your ESTA has been aproved is then your passport and the address to the place you're spending your first night (note that you need the full address: so many people are stumped when asked for the post code).

Comment: Just search US visas https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html

Comment: I'll read through them. Thank you, do you know how long does it take to go through the applications?

Comment: @user8469759 Filling in the ESTA application takes 30 minutes or so. It then takes between a few minutes and three days to process the application.

Comment: Hi, my ESTA has been approved. Do I need to bring any documents with me (regarding the ESTA)?

Comment: @user8469759 You technically only need your passport. I would recommend also bringing the name and contact information for the organiser of the conference, in case there are any issue with border control. This becomes more important if you belong to a demographic that's frequently stopped at borders.